# Excel shortcut opens latest installed version

Tags: excel

First of all yes I posted this on another board but I gave them ample time to answer and received none.

Would it be possible for a shortcut to be able to execute the latest version of MS Excel they have installed? This way people don't need a different shortcut that opens the same document for each version of Excel. Thanks!

For instance Excel 2007 shortcut uses "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"

Excel 2003 shortcut uses "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE"

If the latest the user has 2007 then I want the shortcut to use 2007. If the latest the user has is 2003 then I want it to use 2003.

Comment: All you need to do is change the `Target` field according to the version of the application installed on the users' systems. What problem did you run into?

Comment: I have team members that use multiple versions of excel and I have different VBA code that runs for each version. It's just easier to tell them to download a single shortcut rather storing a bunch of shortcuts for different versions and ask them to choose the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LatestExcel.bat` contained the following, clicking it would have the effect you seek.

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" GOTO L2007
if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\EXCEL.EXE" GOTO L2003
echo "Excel not installed"
pause
GOTO End
:L2007
Call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"
GOTO End
:L2003
Call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\EXCEL.EXE"
:End
```

**Alternative solution**

`CALL`, which I used in the first solution, gives control to another batch file or program but takes control back once that batch file or program has finished.  This is why `CMD.EXE` remains active.  I thought I remembered a batch command that switched control but I cannot find it; I must be thinking of another scripting language.

BTW.  If you Google "windows batch file commands", you will be offered a selection of sites providing tutorials or syntax for batch file commands.  However, I normally create a batch file with the commands `Help` `Pause` or `Help Copy` `Pause`.

For this solution I created two shortcuts, one for Excel 2003 and one for Excel 2007, and placed them in Temp.  I created batch file `PickLatestExcel.bat` with the statements below.  I tried it in a regular folder and on the desktop and in both cases it moved the correct shortcut file and renamed it `Excel`.

I do not know the environment in which you are operating but perhaps these two solutions will give you an idea of what you can achieve with batch files.

```
rem @echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" GOTO L2007
if exist "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\EXCEL.EXE" GOTO L2003
echo "Excel not installed"
pause
GOTO End
:L2007
Copy "C:\Windows\Temp\Excel2007.lnk" Excel.lnk
GOTO End
:L2003
Copy "C:\Windows\Temp\Excel2003.lnk" Excel.lnk 
:End
```

Comment: By the way the terminal cmd.exe lingers after it finishes executing, how to get rid of this?

Comment: My MS-DOS Batch file programming is very rusty.  I seem to recall there is an alternative to `Call` that does not return but I cannot find it.  I will have another look tomorrow.

Comment: @Wes. I hope my alternative solution is closer to your requirement or gives you some ideas on how to meet it.

Comment: Yea that's not really what I'm looking for, I like the original solution better just need to find a way to rid the cmd.exe...